Animate a MWE GIF in R
Could you please tell me why this MWE of an animated GIF, compiled in R, does not animate?
library("ggplot2")
library("gifski")
library("gganimate")
library("dplyr")
library("lubridate")

animate(ggplot(tribble(
~time,          ~y,
"2020-01-01",   2,
"2020-02-01",   4,
"2020-03-01",   3
) %>% mutate(time = as.numeric(ymd(time)))) +
    geom_line(aes(x=time, y=y)) +
    transition_time(time),
    renderer = gifski_renderer(file = "test.gif"))

The result is a still


It's been a bit since I used gganimate, but I believe the way transition_time(time) works is that the first frame will be the first time, the second frame the second time, etc. Your sample data has only one row per time point, but you are using geom_line(), which requires at least 2 points. If you change to geom_point(), I bet you'll see a point that moves, but if you want to use geom_line()  you'll need at least 2 data points at each timepoint.

It also needs debugging details.

Changing transition_time() to transition_reveal() produced a result.

